# Reload in Back/Forward Button doesn't work in IE(11, 10 and 9 tested)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, back, forward

maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't get out of this problem. 
I have a script which reloads the page when a user try to access it by back or forward button. I used a trick in the url to make this thing possible (I edited a script found in the web which checks the existence of a # in the url to force the reload). 
Everything goes well in all browser, but not in IE. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1) {
  url = document.URL+"#";
  location = "#";
} else {
  location.reload(true);
  document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
}
});
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Why do you want to break the browser?

Comment: I have to prevent back/forward button actions 'cause I've got some .animate events on load.
My mind is open to other solutions, but I've to force reload.

Comment: SOLVED.
Used "window.location = 'pagename.html'" instead of "location.reload(true);"